# C# NamedValueCollection ToString Replaces Space

Tags: c#, .net

```
[Test]
public void Temp()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

    nvc.Add("Name", "Mickey Mouse");

    Assert.AreEqual("Name=Mickey Mouse", nvc.ToString());
}
```

In the above simple test, although I expect (and want) the result to be "Name=Mickey Mouse", what I get is "Name=Mickey+Mouse" - the space has been replaced with a +.

How can I keep the original formatting?

I also note that in another test a ":" is replaced by "%3a".

EDIT

Some further info to address comments:

The problem I have is that I'm trying to build up a url string with the query string as per the test in the question. I know that when I post the data via Postman for example with the space in the query string that the post is processed successfully by the API and I have been trying to get the query string generation code under test.

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with Url encoding?

Comment: Good point - I assume that it's an encoding issue but wasn't sure how to "fix" it. Is the answer then that my assertion is just incorrect?

Comment: Well what is it you ultimately want to do here?  Describe your original problem, not the problem with your proposed solution

Comment: question updated to provide some background to the question whilst keeping the specific code sample concise

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual("Name=Mickey Mouse", HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nvc.ToString()))` (using `System.Web`)

Comment: It does HttpUtility.UrlEncode()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.7.2) decoded the string.

> Converts a string that has been encoded for transmission in a URL into a decoded string.

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nvc.ToString())
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4IrHCV)

**Result**

```
Name=Mickey Mouse
```